# statsmodels patsy hypothesis testing

Tags: regression, statsmodels, patsy

Not sure where this belongs so asking this in crossvalidated also. I am running the following regression:
from patsy import dmatrices
import statsmodels.api as sm

```
y, X = dmatrices('M ~ I(4.8*(Q**0.8)) ', data=DF, return_type='dataframe')
res = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

Now I need to test the joint hypothesis that intercept=0 and beta=1. I tried doing this:

```
hyp='Intercept = 0, 4.8*(Q**0.8) = 1'
t=res.f_test(hyp)
```

but got the following error:

```
PatsyError: unrecognized token in constraint
    Intercept = 0, 4.8*(Q**0.8) = 1
```

I also tried

```
hyp='Intercept = 0, I(4.8*(Q**0.8)) = 1'
```

but got

```
PatsyError: unrecognized token in constraint
    Intercept = 0, I(4.8*(Q**0.8)) = 1
```

what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: I think you need to check what parameter names patsy created for `4.8*(Q**0.8)`, e.g. by looking at the `summary()`, and use that in the constraint.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. If you want to use formulas in the hypothesis tests, then you need to use the formula interface instead of providing only y and X. With only y and X, there is no information inside OLS about how they were created. The parameter names should be just generic `const, x1, x2, ..` or whatever column names are available in the DataFrame.

Comment: `hyp = "Intercept=0, I(4.8 * (Q ** 0.8))=1"`  works for me. Note the spacing as used in `X.columns`